# Add extra method to existing web service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap

I would like add more methods to an existing web service. For example, I would like to use the GlobalWheather web service and add more fields to this service in Java.
I can call this service in Eclipse and use the method of this service but I want to add more code to it.

For example this service has two field like this:
[image]

I tested this service in SOAPUI and I see a form like that, but I want to add another field like village.

Comment: you have to have source code or you can make another web service which will use GlobalWeather methods and you can add more methods to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have the source of this `GlobalWheather` service, wherein you can simply add more code to the existing code, what you will need to do is to create a web service of your own part of which wraps over the `GlobalWheather` web service.

This will allow your new service to provide ([wrap up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library)) the existing functionalities provided by `GlobalWheather` and also provide your own extra methods.

As per your question, it will depend on whether this service is open source. If it is, then you *should* be able to find the necessary database schemas and you can thus re-create the database.

If not, which I think is highly likely, then you will need to create your database which will contain information which complements the data you are passing to the web service.

Thus, in your example you could either have a `Village` table which provides a list of villages for which your service will cater for.

Comment: Can I connect the database of this service and add more rows to it ?if I have the source code of this service

Comment: @programmer: I've expanded my answer.